# jQuery wrong math

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with comparing two fields. In console when I run:

```
$("input[name=light]").val() <= $("#units_home #light").text()
```

with Values:

```
$("input[name=light]").val() = 10
$("#units_home #light").text() = 7
```

The result is true. Below is a screenshot of my console.

[image]

Comment: $("input[name=light]").val(10) not =10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `7` is actually a string, so the `10` is also converted to a string (`"10"`). Those two strings are compared alphabetically and character by character:

The first characters are: `7` and `1`, so it sees that `7` is higher.

To compare numbers, parse the second value to a number using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
$("input[name=light]").val() <= parseInt($("#units_home #light").text(), 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to perform a mathematical comparison on strings. Use parseInt to convert them to numbers first:

```
parseInt($("input[name=light]").val()) <= parseInt($("#units_home #light").text())
```